# Need a function for pandas dataframe that identifies equal strings and then assigns to new columns

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, function

I made a pandas df from parts of 2 others:
Here is the pseudocode for what I want to do.
4-column pandas dataframe, values in all columns are single words. 
cols A B C D and I want this: cols A B C D E F 
in pseudcode: 
(for every s in A; 
if s equals any string (not substring) in D; 
write Yes to E (new column) else write No to E; 
if str in B (same row as s) equals str in C (same row as string found in D) write yes to F (new column) 
else write No to F)
The following code works but now I need a function to do what is described above:

```
cols = [1,2,3,5]
df3.drop(df3.columns[cols],axis=1, inplace=True)
df4.drop(df4.columns[1],axis=1, inplace=True)
listi = [df4]
listi.append(df3)
df5 = pd.concat(listi, axis = 1)
```

It should be if i)if x['A'] == x['D'] and ii) if x['B'] == x['C'] and also I need to add column G which is the string found in C or if string not found.

Here is a small sample data set and expected outcome:

```
A B C D
cats cat cat cats
went be have had
tried try enter entering
entering enter try tried
```

Expected outcome

```
A B C D E F G 
cats cat cat cats yes yes cat 
went be have had no no tried 
try entering entering yes no try 
entering enter try tried yes no entering
```

Column G is the word found in C if the word is found else

Comment: Can you provide a small dataset and an example using that dataset?

Comment: Paul, I'm not sure if I understand your example, the first line the one with the cats it's ok, the second I understand the column E and F but not G, can you review that because I think there's something missing there?

Comment: Hi I'll get back a little later and give you what is missing.

Comment: There was stuff missing - best to give full rows of expected outcome The first four columns are the same in input and output. row 2 went,be,have,had,no,no,<empty>:row 3 tried,try,enter,entering,yes,yes,try:row 4 entering,enter,try,tried,yes,yes,entering. There is one change from the original but we'll stick with this newest version.

Answer (score 0):

For what I understood you can apply a lamda to your DataFrame

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Anyway I built a small example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['a','a','a','b'],['b','c','b','b'],['d','d','d','g'],['j','j','c','d']],[1,2,3,4], columns=['A','B','C','D'])
df
#    A  B   C   D
#1   a  a   a   b
#2   b  c   b   b
#3   d  d   d   g
#4   j  j   c   d
df['E']=df.apply(lambda x: 'yes' if x['A'] == x['B'] else 'no', axis=1)
df['F']=df.apply(lambda x: 'yes' if x['C'] == x['D'] else 'no', axis=1)
df
#   A   B   C   D   E   F
#1  a   a   a   b   yes no
#2  b   c   b   b   no  yes
#3  d   d   d   g   yes no
#4  j   j   c   d   yes no
```